# How to loop through an entire XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml, loops, variables, tags

I'm trying to open an XML file and parse through it, looking through its tags and finding the text within each specific tag. If the text within the tag matches a string, I want it remove a part of the string or substitute it with something else.

However, it looks like it is only looking through the first "filter" element in my XML file. It's not doing what's in the remaining "filter" elements. In the second filter element, "regex" is "DFW.+.$" so it should pull that in for the if statement: "if action == 'remove':
if re.match(r"\b(?<=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % regex, mfn_pn, re.IGNORECASE):"
and delete "DFW" and "." if "DFW" is in the first three characters and "." is the last character, where the mfn_pn variable is a barcode inputted by the user, something similar to ATL-157-1815, DFW-184-8378., ATL-324-3243., DFW-432-2343. However, this is not being done.

The XML file has the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <filter>
        <regex>ATL|LAX|DFW</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char></end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>DFW.+\.$</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char>-1</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\-</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\s</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex> T&amp;R$</regex >
        <start_char></start_char>
        <end_char>-4</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
</metadata>
```

The Python code I'm using is:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

# filters.xml is the file that holds the things to be filtered
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("filters.xml")

# Get the data in the XML file 
root = tree.getroot()

# Loop through filters
for x in root.findall('filter'):

    # Find the text inside the regex tag
    regex = x.find('regex').text

    # Find the text inside the start_char tag
    start_prim = x.find('start_char')
    
    # If the element exists assign its text start variable
    start = start_prim.text if start_prim is not None else ''
    start_int = int(start) if start is not None else ''

    # Find the text inside the end_char tag
    end_prim = x.find('end_char')

    # If the element exists assign its text end variable
    end = end_prim.text if end_prim is not None else ''
    end_int = int(end) if end is not None else ''

    # Find the text inside the action tag
    action = x.find('action').text

    if action == 'remove':
        if re.match(r"\b(?<=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % regex, mfn_pn, re.IGNORECASE):
            if end_int == '':
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[start_int:]
                print(mfn_pn)
            else: 
                mfn_pn = mfn_pn[start_int:end_int]
                print(mfn_pn)

    elif action == 'substitute':
        mfn_pn = re.sub(r"\b(?<=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % regex, '', mfn_pn)

    return mfn_pn
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete code example? What is `mfn_pn` supposed to be? When running your provided code snippet, it's undefined. **Additionally:** By having a `return` statement inside your loop, you are exiting the loop after a single iteration.

Comment: @gallen mfn_pn variable is a barcode inputted by the user, something similar to ATL-157-1815, DFW-184-8378., ATL-324-3243., DFW-432-2343. How would I place the return statement to not get only a single iteration? I tried placing outside the loop but I'm still getting an error.

Comment: first: `return` can be used only inside function but your code is not in function. Second: you should rather create list for all result before `for`-loop `results = []`, and use `results.append(mfn_pn)` instead of `return mfn_pn`. And after loop you can dislay `print(results)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,utils
import re

def test(f='filters.xml', pn='ATL-157-1815'):
    doc = SimplifiedDoc()
    doc.loadFile(f)

    # Get the data in the XML file 
    root = doc.select('metadata')
    # Loop through filters
    for x in root.selects('filter'):

        # Find the text inside the regex tag
        regex = x.regex.text

        # Find the text inside the start_char tag
        start = x.start_char.text

        # Find the text inside the end_char tag
        end = x.end_char.text

        # Find the text inside the action tag
        action = x.action.text

        if action == 'remove':
            if re.match(r"\b(?<=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % regex, pn, re.IGNORECASE):
                if end == '':
                    pn = pn[int(start):]
                    print(pn)
                else: 
                    pn = pn[int(start):int(end)]
                    print(pn)

        elif action == 'substitute':
            pn = re.sub(r"\b(?<=\w)%s\b(?!\w)" % regex, '', pn)

    return pn

pn = test()
print (pn)
```